# Split ignoring part of regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

My goal is to get the length till the nth occurrence of `<br>` tag in javascript so I am splitting them up.

I am trying regex

```
((.|\s)*?<br\s?/?>){2}  //2 is the max number of lines(br tags) allowed.
```

While this is working fine in regexBuddy

but the string is splitted into multiple parts ignoring the `<br\s?/?>` part in browser.
you can view a fiddle [here](https://jsbin.com/xidaza/edit?html,js,console)

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Could you provide what the desired result of the fiddle should be ? i mean what the `length` should return

Comment: length of `this is a test for multiline.<br />

..<br />` i.e 45

Comment: the number of character till the nth occurrence of a `br` tag

Comment: Do not use `(.|\s)` to match anything-including-newlines; it's *extremely* inefficient.  Use `[\s\S]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, which will split the string up in to pieces based on the regular expression. This will not include your regular expression match. In your case the first section of the string matches your regular expression, so you would have an empty string at index 0 and everything after the regular expression match in index 1.

You should try to use the [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method instead, which will return an array of the pieces of the string that matched your regular expression.

```
var str=$('#op').html();
console.log(str.match(/(([\s\S])*?<br\s?\/?>){2}/i)[0].length);
```

[See code](https://jsbin.com/dujewazuso/edit?html,js,console).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't `exec` make more sense than `split` in this case?

```
var str=$('#op').html();
var match = /((.|\s)*?<br\s?\/?>){2}/i.exec(str);
if( match )
  console.log(match[0].length);
```